# Local PDF file is not opening in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, uiwebview

I have the pdf file in local resource folder i want to open this file using UIWebView and user can read. But the PDF file is not displaying to read.

```
NSString *pathToBundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
 NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathToBundle];
 NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Insupen_User_Guide" ofType:@"pdf"];
 NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
 //CGRect fullScreenRect=[[UIScreen mainScreen]applicationFrame];
 catalogue=[[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,400,600,600)];
 [catalogue loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:baseURL];

  catalogue.delegate=self;
 [self.view addSubview:catalogue];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this.

```
NSString *strPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Insupen_User_Guide" ofType:@"pdf"];
[catalogue loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[strPath stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]]];
```

maybe this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"HR" ofType:@"pdf"];
NSURL *targeturl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targeturl];
//    _webview = [[UIWebView alloc]init];
[[_webview scrollView] setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 500) animated:YES];


[_webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"window.scrollTo(0.0, 50.0)"]];
[_webview loadRequest:request];
```

// worked for me perfectly you can try this

Answer (score 0):

You can also display PDF in `UIDocumentInteractionController` using this.

```
UIDocumentInteractionController *docController = [UIDocumentInteractionController  interactionControllerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"PDF file name" ofType:@"pdf"]]];

    docController.delegate = self;

    //[DocView addSubview:docController];
    [docController presentPreviewAnimated:YES];
```

And add these delegate methods in your class.

```
#pragma mark  documentInteractionController methods

- (UIViewController *)documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview:(UIDocumentInteractionController *)controller {
    return self;
}

- (UIView *)documentInteractionControllerViewForPreview:(UIDocumentInteractionController *)controller {
    return self.view;
}

- (CGRect)documentInteractionControllerRectForPreview:(UIDocumentInteractionController *)controller {
    return self.view.frame;
}
- (BOOL)documentInteractionController:(UIDocumentInteractionController *)controller   canPerformAction:(SEL)action{
    return FALSE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the code you posted you are turning the contents of the PDF file into a UTF8 encoded string and displaying the string inside the web view, this is not what you want.

Instead, you need to make a NSURLRequest pointing to the local PDF and load the request in the web view like so

```
NSString *pdfPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Insupen_User_Guide" ofType:@"pdf"];
NSURL *pdfUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pdfPath];
NSURLRequest *pdfUrlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:pdfUrl];
[catalogue loadRequest:pdfUrlRequest];
```